# How to set language to english when using "master.dbo.sysmessages" in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I used this Query retrieve all server error message but it giving me some `unreadable` language like:

[image]

Here's my script:

```
SET LANGUAGE us_english;
SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysmessages
```

But it returns me the same from above result.

My Question is How to make this as `English` Language?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Um, that's a table that contains all the different error messages in all the different languages. If you want to view all of the different error messages in English only, you could do something like `SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysmessages WHERE msglangid = 1033`

Answer (score 0):

To configure the default language with your sql server, Open sql server and follow below steps

1. In Object Explorer, right-click a server and select Properties.
2. Click the Misc server settings node.
3. In the Default language for users box, choose the language in which
   Microsoft SQL Server should display system messages. The default
   language is English.

for your reference please check attached image.
[image: Set Default Language in Sql Server database Object]

Comment: Also, `Default Full-Text Language` to `msglangid` value from `[sys].[syslanguages]` or page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-syslanguages-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15